# Controllers ou Resources do JAX-RS em comparação com Spring MVC

Tags: java, java-ee, jax-rs

Eu que vim do Spring estou com dificuldades para entender o funcionamento do JAX-RS em uma aplicação JAVA EE. Tenho uma aplicação rodando em um servidor de aplicação Wildfly. Criei uma classe para usar o JAX-RS chamada AgendamentoEmailController. Ele basicamente tem um método GET que listar meus e-mails e retorna em forma de JSON.

```
@Path("emails")
public class AgendamentoEmailController {

@Inject
private AgendamentoEmailServico agendamentoEmailServico;

@GET
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listar() {
    return Response.ok(agendamentoEmailServico.listar()).build();
}
```

Também criei uma classe para estender de Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class AgendamentoEmailApplication extends Application {

}
```

Nos meus estudos foi falado que essas classes como a AgendamentoEmailController que possuem as ações são comumente chamadas de Controllers ou Resources. Aí apareceram as dúvidas que não consegui sanar:

1 - Cada uma dessas classes do JAX-RS são um Servlet? Mesmo não implementando ou estendendo ou implementando nada referente a um servlet? Acredito que sim, mas a dúvida veio por conta dessa nomenclatura de controllers. No Spring MVC os controllers não são Servlets, lá possui um controlador central com um dispatcher Servlet que chama nossos controllers que possuem as ações.

2 - No JAVA EE juntamente com o JAX-RS tem alguma tecnologia que trabalha com um dispatcher servlet igual ao Spring MVC que possui o seu controlador central, ou seja, um único servlet?